Can high intelligence lead to profound ignorance?

Christopher Langan has one of the highest IQs ever recorded and can
claim to be one of the most intelligent people ever. His IQ test was
literally off the charts, and at an early age, he taught himself
advanced mathematics, physics, philosophy, Latin and Greek. He could
also learn languages incredibly fast, having a solid understanding by
just skimming through a textbook. Yet Christopher Langan has many
abhorrent, incorrect, and absurd beliefs. For example, he believes
9/11 was orchestrated by George Bush. He is an antisemite, is opposed
to interracial relationships and is championed by Neo-Nazis. The list
here goes on and on – there are countless examples of highly
intelligent people who believe appalling, contradictory and clearly
wrong things.


Intelligence can be very seductive and trick you into believing you
are vastly more knowledgeable than you really are. It leads people to
fail to interpret the knowledge they have acquired accurately.
Instead, it fools them into believing they have justified true beliefs
in areas they are more ignorant than they realise. The culprit here,
as in many areas of our internal world, is the ego, which can create
an arrogance which inflates as more knowledge is acquired.


It would seem, therefore, that intelligence is less desirable than it
appears to be. True, it allows for the gaining of knowledge more
easily, but it is no guarantee that that knowledge is being used for
doing good. I find a far better barometer of someone is, ironically,
when they fully accept how ignorant they are, are genuinely humble
about what they know and can suggest ideas whilst being wary that they
may not be entirely sure about them. Most of all, when they are happy
and willing to say, ‘I don’t know’.

https://mantality.co.uk/mind/on-intelligence-knowledge-ignorance-and-wisdom/#:~:text=Intelligence%20is%20a%20very%20complex,as%20a%20lack%20of%20knowledge.
From Boeing executives to Trump believers, one could notice a proliferation of ignorance in the modern world.
Is it a new phenomenon or an old philosophy?

I vote to close this post because the link is no reliable source, the post builds on an unclear opposition (new phenomenon - old philosophy), and possibly evokes opinion-based answers.

That is the problem with IQ tests: they don't, for example, test for emotional intelligence, or practical ability.

I like the question but would like it to be a bit more neatly presented.

@JuliusHamilton - When the question is closed within one hour, fire and forget quality creep in.

9/11 is a ¼ century ago. Why not talk of the near exact analog now? BTW I find this a significant question but it's too "thin". This site has a "minimum verbiage padding" requirement which is more than I would like. But your questions are too "thin" even for me

I remember by association: My programming teacher, an exceptional brilliant CSist was like this. For his own thesis presentation he walked into class, wrote an equation on the board and said: For my thesis I solved this equation. Any questions? No one spoke. He said My presentation is over and strolled out... All in less than 5 minutes!!

Your final question conflates phenomena and philosophies. Phenomena, even social phenomena, are not always underpinned by a formal philosophy. E.g. most human beings devote significant attention to romantic love but there is a dearth of philosophy books about it.
So I take the question as meaning "Is it a new or old phenomenon?"
This is not to disminish the philosophical nature of the question. The Freudian tradition aside, Western philosophers have historically invested a lot into u nderstanding and glorifying reason (essentially logic, language and science), seen as what differentiates us from other animals and as our best recourse in life. Emotions, the other dimension of the human experience, have classically been relegated to the status of "passions", i.e., things we passively endure, and de-emphasised.
And yet there is such a thing as emotional intelligence, even though modern philosophers haven't explored it much... It might be what Saint-Exupery had in mind when he wrote: "It is only with the heart that one can see rightly; what is essential is invisible to the eye." Or what Rabelais pointed out with his “Science without conscience is but the ruin of the soul”.
So to me, the question ought to be about the possible negative consequences for society of an admitedly excessive emphasis on reason as opposed to emotions in some Western philosophic traditions. Have we bet too much on reason, and is this related -- did it contribute -- to the rise of heartless ideologies such as fascism or communism in the past century? These ideologies were internally logical (even brilliant in the case of Marxism) and pretended to scientificity. We know today that they are "bad" because of the poison fruits they bore, but the Nazis saw themselves as perfectly reasonable.
At the time, many scientists agreed. One case that comes to mind is Ettore Majorana, a brilliant young Sicilian physicist in the 30's, who during a study trip to Germany wrote apologetic letters about Nazism to his colleagues back in Rome, including to Enrico Fermi, his mentor, whose wife Laura was Jewish. Fermi was horrified by Majorana's letters. And yet he thought the kid was a genius... Majorana was a case of "science without conscience".

"Olivier5" - Thank you! "negative consequences for society of an admittedly excessive emphasis on reason" - Now I see the reason, why would they let Hollywood multiply ignorance in the world.

Ignorance is much safer for society than half-baked intelligence.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance My point is simply that emotional intelligence matters just as much or even more than computational intelligence, and that people who are intoxicated with their own computational intelligence can easily disregard or ignore emotions (including their own) as "unimportant", and this way they can easily become monsters. Reason is a good servant but a bad master.

@andrós It's all forgotten, literally, meaning I have no idea what happened "before".

@Olivier5 - I am interested in a global balance of good and bad, intelligent and ignorant. But you opened my eyes to the fact that, similar to fascist or communist ideologies, an organized culture of ignorance is also a kind of ideology with a distinct purpose.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance There are studies and books about "the dumbing down of America" (a phrase coined by Carl Sagan), some saying that it was a deliberate effort to disempower the American democracy, and prevent social mixity.

@Olivier5 - Wow, Thank you. For the first time, I saw my own thoughts from outside: "lowest common denominator programming, credulous presentations on pseudoscience and superstition, but especially a kind of celebration of ignorance.” https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/dumbing-down-america-20-tim-elmore-pywoe/

But trying to spoon-feed culture could backfire as well. The immigrants from Cuba and the USSR are on par with American evangelicals in their extreme right views.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance I guess you are right -- when "culture" is just the official, state-supported version of history, literature, gender, etc. Then it becomes boring, and control-oriented. A fine line.
